# How to run a code after a return statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, queue

I encountered an issue while solving an algorithmic problem yesterday, which goes thus.

```
  remove() {
    // your code here
    if(!this.arr.length) {
      return -1;
    }
    else if(this.arr.length) {
     return this.arr[0];
     this.arr.splice(0, 1);
    }
  }
```

**Note:- This is part of one of the class methods.**

I wanted to get the item in the zero index before splicing that same item out. Then I realized that a code after a return statement is called an *unreachable code* and therefore, won't be executed.

Comment: Please don't update a question with information you got from the answers. Rolled back to original version.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case you can use the *return value* of `splice`: it returns the slice that was extracted, and so it contains the value you want to return.

As a side note, the `else` part does not need an `if` to test the array length, as that condition is guaranteed to be true.

```
  remove() {
    if(!this.arr.length) {
      return -1;
    }
    else {
     return this.arr.splice(0, 1)[0];
    }
  }
```

Note that for this particular splicing, there is a shortcut method: `shift`:

```
  remove() {
    if(!this.arr.length) {
      return -1;
    }
    else {
     return this.arr.shift();
    }
  }
```

You can shorten this with the conditional operator:

```
  remove() {
    return this.arr.length ? this.arr.shift() : -1;
  }
```

And if you are certain that your array will not have `null` or `undefined` entries, you can even do:

```
  remove() {
    return this.arr.shift() ?? -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an old tricky solution.

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
 function remove() {
     try {
         // your code here
        if(!arr.length) {
          return -1;
        }
        else if(arr.length) {
         return arr[0];
       
        }
    } finally {
         arr.splice(0, 1);
    } 

  }
  console.log(remove());
  console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

And so, I came over here for an answer and found a setTimeout solution that didn't really work for my code.
So, I figured out a solution that goes thus.

```
  remove() {
    // your code here
    if(!this.arr.length) {
      return -1;
    }
    else() {
     let firstEl = this.arr[0];
     this.arr.splice(0, 1);
     return firstEl;
    }
  }
```

store what you wish to return in a variable, then execute your code afterward before returning the value you stored. In that way, it is hierarchical in some sense.